Current-limiter circuit messes with voltage measurement in my 12 V battery balancer PCB, and I dont understand why?
I am currently designing a passive battery balancer for a battery pack with three 12 V batteries, the balancer needs to discharge the battery that has the highest voltage. The INA148UA difference amplifier gives a voltage that is readable with a microcontroller, 3.11 V is the highest output and is equal to 15.2 V voltage from the battery. Between the connection of the battery and the difference amplifier is a current-limiter circuit that is only enabled when a microcontroller is connected to the PCB.
I have done reviews with colleagues at work, and they said that this design should work, but when I ordered this PCB the output values were different from the ones I calculated/expected.
The picture below shows the measurements I did with an Arduino, nmbr 1 is 8 V and nmbr 15 is 15 V, with steps of 0.5 V. So I did some research and testing with the PCB, and found out that the current-limiter circuit is messing with my measurements. When I removed the P-channel MOSFET and soldered the source and drain together, it worked as it should. But I can't seem to find the reason the MOSFET messes with my measurements.

So my question is: Why/how does the current-limiting circuit effect my measurements and how can I fix this?
(FYI the 330R 1 W resistor is not the resistor that is going to be used, the resistor is going to be one with higher power rating)


So what are the actual voltages at the drains of Q1, Q5 and Q9 during each of these measurements? BTW, you're over-driving the gates of Q3, Q7 and Q11, which have an absolute max rating of ±10 V.

Is there a connection between 0V and GND in the circuit? This is needed for Q4,Q8 and Q12 to properly turn on

@DaveTweed The drain voltage of Q1 = 19.3V, Q5 = -7.84V and Q9 = -23V. The gate-to-source voltage is ±16V, so I should be fine.

@Ferrybig No there is no connection between the two, but is it okay for the 0V connection (negative terminal) of the battery to be connected to the ground?

Of course it's okay -- it's required for the circuit to work at all. Without it, you can't get a definite value for Vgs on Q1, Q5 or Q9.

You need a connection between the battery and the circuit ground for your mosfet's to work.
Look at the circuity around Q9. To activate this mosfet, you need to lower the voltage on the gate. For this, some current needs to flow through R23. This current comes from a battery connection and because electricity flows in a loop, it needs to make its way back to the battery.
Connect GND to the 0V point of the battery. (if you have a requirement for having both sides isolated, you need to find a different solution, you can do something similar to the optocouplers you used at the discharge side, or you can use a resistive opto-coupler that has a high value in the off mode)
